# Get the last "X" day from today?

Tags: java, math

I ran into a simple problem, which I solved ( I didn't give up ). However, I think that there is some more neat and tricky solution.
 The problem is as follow : Return the date of the last X day before today. For example If today is  Tuesday, July 09, 2013 and I want the last Friday the answer would be Friday, July 05, 2013.

My solution is as follow :

```
    public Date dateOfLast(int day) {

        int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        int daysDifferences = today - day;

        int daysToSubtract;

        if (day < today) {
            //last day seems to be in current week !
            //for example Fr > Tu.
            daysToSubtract = -(Math.abs(daysDifferences));
        } else {
            //7- ( difference between days )!
            //last day seems to be in the previous,thus we subtract the the days differences from 7
            // and subtract the result from days of month.
            daysToSubtract = -(7 - Math.abs(daysDifferences));
        }
        //subtract from days of month.
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysToSubtract);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Anyone give me a mathematical formula or a simpler solution, if any ?

Comment: Your solution looks good to me.

Comment: thank you but I think there is a better one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int daysToSubtract = ((today - day) + 7) % 7;
```

should be OK, if I'm not mistaken.

For example

```
today = 4
day = 2
daysToSubtract = ((4 - 2) + 7) % 7 = 2 : correct

today = 2
day = 4
daysToSubtract = ((2 - 4) + 7) % 7 = 5 : correct
```

Comment: can you explain the part ? %7

Comment: It's the modulo operator. It computes the remainder of the integer division: 0 % 7 = 0; 1 % 7 = 1; ...; 7 % 7 = 0; 8 % 7 = 1; ...

Comment: Yes you are 90% right except that I need to subtract days thus 
int daysToSubtract =-( ((today - day) + 7) % 7 );

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks good to me. But a tip: you shouldn't need to use `Math.abs` here, you should know which of your variables, `today` or `day`, is bigger in each branch of your `if`-statement:

```
if (day < today)
    daysToSubtract = day - today;  // 'today' is bigger
else
    daysToSubtract = day - today - 7;  // 'day' is bigger
```

or just

```
int daysToSubtract = day - today - ((day < today) ? 0 : 7);
```

Notice that we don't need the `daysDifferences` variable anymore.

Comment: You probably mean + 7. Otherwise, the days to subtract will be negative, and you'll thus add days.

Comment: @JBNizet I think the name of the variable is misleading; it looks like we want it to be negative.